# Backbone.js + KendoUI - Routing, Views, and Structuring with Grid

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, kendo-ui

**What I'm doing:**

I'm creating a sample app that shows how to incorporate Kendo UI controls with Backbone.js using Rails 3 as a JSON server.

So far, I have Backbone Views that are managing templates in an erb file and a Backbone Router that is managing the Views themselves - depending on the links that are clicked.

When this is finished, I want to make it all available as a tutorial to help folks who want to get into Backbone - and KendoUI (which is pretty damn cool as well).

**The Problem:**

The Kendo grid is not rendering through the Users View render method - even though it's container template is.

Right now, I am having to render the grid from the Users method of the Router - after the router has rendered the User view.

[image]

**It seems odd that the template renders, but the grid does not - or am I missing something?**

Maybe it will be simpler to understand once you see the code:

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Kendo Grid Test</h1>

<div id="nav"></div>


<div id="container">

<!-- The templates below will be placed  here dynamically    -->

</div>

<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<script type="text/template" id="users-grid-template">  
    <p>Users Grid Template</p>

    <div id="users-grid"></div> 


</script>

<script type="text/template" id="posts-grid-template">  
    <div id="posts-grid"></div> 
</script>



<script type="text/template" id="nav-template">
  <div>
    <ul id="nav_container">
        <li><a href="#users">Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#posts">Posts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</script>
```

**Backbone Users View**

```
window.UsersView = Backbone.View.extend({

            initialize: function() {                                
                _.bindAll(this, "render");
                this.usersGrid = _.template($("#users-grid-template").html());
                this.render().el;                   
            },

            render: function() {                
                $(this.el).html(this.usersGrid).fadeIn();
                return this;
            }

        });
```

**Backbone Router**

```
window.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes: {
            'users': 'users',
            'posts': 'posts'

        },

        initialize: function() {            
            this.usersView = new UsersView;
        },      

        posts: function() {
            var container = $("#container");
            container.empty();
        },      


        users: function() { 

            var container = $("#container");
            container.empty();          

            container.append(this.usersView.render().el);

            var UsersData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/users",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    }
                });             

                var grid = $("#users-grid").kendoGrid({

                    dataSource: UsersData,

                    columns: [
                    {
                        field: "first_name",
                        title: "First Name"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "last_name",
                        title: "Last Name",

                    }]
                });

                container.append(grid);             
        }           
    });



    window.App = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
```

As you can see, the Kendo UI grid is dynamically generated and placed into the `<div id="users-grid"></div>` of the "users-grid-template".  But, I have to do a separate 'append' method in order to get the grid into the template.  This seems unnecessary.

It seems like I should be able to place all of this...

[image]

... inside of the UsersView Render method - without having to use the append method.  But I can't get that to work.

**Any suggestions on how to structure this?  Or whether or not my current code is structured correctly?**

Advice much appreciated!

---

**EDIT - Simplified Solution (thanks to Derick)**

I realized that I was over-complicating this.  I was trying to use Backbone to do what Kendo was already doing - managing its grid and datasource.

Since Backbone is so modular, and all I really needed for the moment was it's Router, I removed all the views - except for the Navigation view - and just used the Router and let Kendo do its thing.

I think the solution is much simpler and easier to manage code.  (at least for me)

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        window.Navigation = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#nav"),          

        initialize: function() {            
            _.bindAll(this, "render");
            this.nav = $("#nav-template").html();
            this.render().el;
        },  

        render: function() {
            $(this.el).html(this.nav);
            return this;
        }



        });

    window.nav = new Navigation;  

    window.AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes: {
            'users': 'users',
            'posts': 'posts'

        },

        initialize: function() {            
            var container = $("#container");
            //container.html("#users-grid");
        },      

        posts: function() {
            var container = $("#container");
            container.empty();
        },      


        users: function() { 

            var container = $("#container");
            usersTemplate = _.template($("#users-grid-template").html());
            container.empty(); 
            container.html(usersTemplate);

            var UsersData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/users",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    }
                });             

                $("#users-grid").kendoGrid({

                    dataSource: UsersData,

                    columns: [
                    {
                        field: "first_name",
                        title: "First Name"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "last_name",
                        title: "Last Name",

                    }]
                });                              
        }           
    });

    window.App = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();




// Closing jquery tag    
});
```

Hopefully someone will find this useful.

Next step - apply CRUD to this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the problem is caused by lack of scoping the selector when trying to call `.kendoGrid`. Stuffing your contents in to the `el.html(...)` doesn't attach your view's `el` to the DOM, so a call to `$("#users-grid")` doesn't have anything to find, yet.

You can still call `kendoGrid` on the view's el, but you have to scope your "#user-grid" selector to the view to do it:

```
Backbone.View.extend({

  render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.usersGrid);

    this.$("#user-grid").kendoGrid({
      // kendo grid options here 
    });
  }

});
```

calling `this.$` as a function on a view is a shortcut method on the view, to use the `el` as the context for your jquery selector. It's the same as calling `this.$el.find("#users-grid")`

FWIW: I'm using Kendo a lot these days, and loving it with Backbone. I haven't yet run in to a Kendo control that needs any real special handling outside of a view's render method.

Comment: Hey Derick - thanks so much for taking a look at my problem.  I'm still having some issues, but I attempted to incorporate the changes you suggested and I made an edit up-top so that you can see the full code.  Maybe you can tell where I'm still going wrong.  I feel like I'm on the edge of understanding this, but I'm still missing something fundamental.  I've been banging around with it for a few hours and now my mind has decided to take vacation :)

Comment: in the new code, you're rendering the view twice - once in the initialize method of the view and once in the router. get rid of one of the calls to `.render()` ... i would remove it from the view's initialize method, personally. that may be causing any remaining problems

Comment: Hey man, when you said I'm rendering the view twice, I got to thinking - I'm trying to get Backbone to manage views, but the Kendo grid and datasource are really already doing that for me.  I'm trying to recreate the work with Backbone when it's unnecessary - at least for what I'm doing now.  I'll save the views for when I need more custom control later.  Thanks again!